# Determine an invertible matrix $S \in \operatorname{Mat}_3(\mathbb{R})$ such that $S^{-1}AS$ is a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Consider the matrix

$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
2 & 2 & 2 \\
-1 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\in \text{Mat}_3(\mathbb{R})
$$

Then I have to determine an invertible matrix $S \in \operatorname{Mat}_3(\mathbb{R})$ such that $S^{-1}AS$ is a diagonal matrix.

**My attempt**

If I have understood what I have to do correctly I need to find the eigenvectors for the matrix $A$. In an earlier question, I calculated the eigenvalues which gave me that 
$$
t_1 = t_2 = 0 \ \text{and} \ t_3 =2
$$
and afterwards the eigenspaces in order to calculate the geometric multiplicity which gave me the following basis

$$\operatorname{Span}(1,-2,1)^T
$$
and
$$
\operatorname{Span}(-1,1,1)^T
$$
but where will the last basis come from that I need to have in order to construct my matrix $S$? I thought that as $t_1 = t_2 = 0$ they would have the same basis but if I construct
$$
S = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & -1 \\
-2 & -2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and afterwards find the inverse of $S$ and calculate $S^{-1}AS$ I don't get the desired result as it should be
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
if I am not mistaken. I am not sure where my mistake is. Can you help me in the right direction?

Comment: Your eigenvalues are clearly incorrect since the trace of this matrix ie equal to $4$, which is not equal to the sum of your eigenvalues. When you computed eigenvectors for $2$ you should’ve ended up with a two-dimensional space. Double-check how you did that.

Answer (score 1):

I have examined the matrix, it has eigenvalues $2,2, 0$, rather than $0,0,2$.

Let's compute $A-2I=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & -1 \\ 2 & 0 & 2\\ -1 & 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$. Rank of $A-2I$ is $1$, hence, there are two independent eigenvectors corresponding to $2$, that is the geometric multiplicty is $2$. Obviously $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector for eigenvalue 2. Use the eigenvectors to construct $S$.

I will let you take it from here.

Comment: Thank you Siong. I got the correct result now. But I am not sure why $(0,1,0)^T$ is an eigenvector as well. We have that $$
E_A(2) = N(A - 2 \cdot I) = N\left(
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & -1 \\
2 & 0 & 2 \\
-1 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\right) \sim 
N \left( \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} \right) $$ which gives me the $(-1,1,1)^T$ is a basis but how do I get the one you have mentioned?

Comment: One possible way is notice that the last matrix that you show above is in RREF, $x_2$ and $x_3$ are free variables,  and the equation tells me that we just need $x_1=-x_3$. There are no restriction on $x_2$. in particular $(0,1,0)$ is in the nullspace.

Comment: So I could pick whatever basis I want as long as $x_1 = -x_3$? I just tried $(2,1,-2)^T$ which also gave the desired result. Would this be ok aswell?

Comment: You can use any eigenvector for eigenvalue 0 and any two linearly independent eigenvectors for eigenvalue 2.